# haml syntax - better way of writing this?

Tags: ruby, haml, staticmatic

I have a config file full of this....

```
   - if current_page.include? "test_string_one"
      - @total_index = 3
      - @next_location = '../random_string/page0.html'
      - @next_name = 'title 2'

    - if current_page.include? "test_string_two"
      - @total_index = 10
      - @next_location = '../another_random_string/page0.html'
      - @next_name = 'title 3'
```

Is there a cleaner way of writing this? Using [Staticmatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.com).

I see there are filters available in haml. Should all this be in `:ruby` filter?

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743291/haml-syntax-better-way-of-writing-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would be best in a helper.

it might look like this:

```
module SomeHelper

  def page_options
    @page_options ||= begin
      options = {}

      if current_page.include? "test_string_one"
         options[:total_index] = 3
         options[:next_location] = '../random_string/page0.html'
         options[:next_name] = 'title 2'
      elsif current_page.include? "test_string_two"
         options[:total_index] = 10
         options[:next_location] = '../another_random_string/page0.html'
         options[:next_name] = 'title 3'
      end

      options
    end

  end

end
```

Then, in each page you need it, you could access the options like this: `page_options[:total_index]`

Comment: Seem to be coming up with an error - I've saved htis file as page_helper.rb in helpers - staticmatic/mixins/helpers.rb:13:in `load_helper': (eval):1:in `load_helper': uninitialized constant Haml::Helpers::PageHelper (NameError)

Comment: That's because SomeHelper should be saved as some_helper.rb in helpers